# Write a function that can ignore specific filter parameters in R

Tags: r, function, dplyr

I want to write a function with several inputs.
Each input adjusts a particular filter parameter in a dplyr pipeline.

I am struggling with how to turn on/off the grep parameter,
that is, I want to have the ability to completely ignore the grep line

My dataframe (df), has three variables (sent, repeat, cases)

Here is my function:

```
my_filter <- function(df, a, b, c){ 

df <<- df %>%
          filter(sent != a,
                repeat != b,
                 !grepl("_v", cases)) 
}
```

I would like the "c" argument to allow me to ignore the last line in the pipeline !grepl("_v", cases)
how do I set "c" such that it controls the presence/absence of that line?

Comment: Don't try to do this within a single `filter()`. Instead, have individual `filter()` commands wrapped in `if()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest something like this:

```
my_filter = function(df, a, b, c = TRUE) {
    result = df %>% filter(
      sent != a,
      repeat_col != b
    )
    if(c) result = result %>% filter(!grepl("_v", cases, fixed = TRUE))
    return(result)
}
```

This handles the conditional as you asked. If you set `c` to `FALSE`, the last condition won't be applied. (In other cases, you can also test for `if(missing(c))` to check if the `c` parameter is supplied by the user or not.)

I also don't use global assignment, because you should basically never use it, `return`ing a result lets the result name be chose by the user, instead of picking it for them and potentially overwriting something they already had.

The `fixed = TRUE` is just for a bit of efficiency since your pattern is an exact match, not a regular expression.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another option :

```r
library(dplyr)
my_filter <- function(df, a = FALSE, b = FALSE, c = TRUE){ 
  df %>%
    filter(Sepal.Width != a,
           Sepal.Length != b,
           c | !grepl("v", Species)) 
}

dim(iris %>% my_filter)
#> [1] 150   5

dim(iris %>% my_filter(c=FALSE))
#> [1] 50  5
```